# While Trying to def: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was using this code in Python 2.7 to produce a new number by:

```
def Alg(n):
    n=((n**2)-1)/4
    return n
```

and I get the error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: how are you calling this ?

Comment: How do you call `Alg`? `Alg(None)`?

Answer (score 4):

Somehow, you're passing `None` when you call this function, this is what's happening:

```
Alg(None)
```

... So `n` is `None` inside the function, causing the error. In other words: the problem is not in the function, it's in the point where you're *calling* it.

Also a word of warning - you're performing a division between integers, better play it safe and make sure that at least one of the division's operands is a decimal, or else you could loose precision:

```
def Alg(n):               # there's no need to reassign n
    return ((n**2)-1)/4.0 # notice the .0 part at the end
```

Comment: For the division, it's much simpler to do `from __future__ import division` at the beginning of your file to get the new version of the division operator, which always does a true vision. See: http://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code works perfectly fine to me, but as an alternative you can use `pow` from `math` module.

```py
import math as m
def Alg(n):
    n=(m.pow(n,2) -1)/4
    return n 
print(Alg(3))
```

Comment: I think you should point out to OP that there is case where `n` can be `None` which is the issue that OP is facing.